# flask template problem with included blocks

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Hi i have some problems getting blocks displayed in my template.
I have 5 files. 3 are included in the base.html and one does extends from it.

Problems are the blocks called meta and footer in header and footer file.
They are just empty in my index.html.

Only the content block is working which is declared in base.html file directly.
navigation.html is working fine but has no blocks declared.

Is it a problem to include files with blocks in base.html file template or did i miss something?

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block meta %}
    {% endblock %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarSupportedContent">
                {% include 'navigation.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

footer.html

```
</body>
<footer>
    {% block footer %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

base.html

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block meta %}
    <title>Titel for index page</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Willkommen bei Brand{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <p>This block works</p>
{% endblock %}
```

navigation.html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ active_home }}" aria-current="page" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ active_contact }}" aria-current="page" href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ active_impress }}" aria-current="page" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Impressum</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a problem to include files with blocks in base.html file template or did i miss something?

Blocks are not visible outside inheritance chain. If you mark a block with `required`, you will see the error:

```
{% block meta required %}
```

```sh
"Required block 'meta' not found"
```

`include`'d template is rendered as a separate inheritance chain, thus it will not see blocks from index.html.

> The include tag is useful to include a template and return the rendered contents of that file into the current namespace
> https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#include

You should not expect your blocks be passed to `include`'d templates, and design template inheritance accordingly. For example, see [base template in jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#template-inheritance)